# split string with variable length in powershell

Tags: powershell

I guess my question is a bit stupid but I am a total newbie. I have to get substrings out of strings like this:

```
DistinguishedName : CN=xyz,OU=Users,OU=abc,OU=asd,DC=qwe,DC=yxc
```

that should look like `CN=xyz,OU=Users,OU=abc,OU=asd,DC=qwe,DC=yxc`. They are variable in length. Do you guys have any suggestions how to do it?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hi @nu11ahnung. Sounds like you might have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) occuring here. Can you explain what your wider aims are?

Comment: There were some formating Problems in my post. There are actually two empty lines before DistinguishedName and 3 after the last word

Comment: How did you obtain this string(s) in the first place? As @gvee says you may be trying to solve an XY Problem here

Comment: I obtained the string from my companies AD using  Get-ADUser -Filter 'sAMAccountName -eq "xyz"' | Format-List DistinguishedName

Comment: Instead of `| Format-List DistinguishedName`, use `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName`. `Format-List` creates formatted output (hence the name). If you don't want the formatting, don't use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what I need. I hope you apoogize my ignorance

Comment: No problem. Next time include the whole command and your output (text, not screenshot). With all the information included someone could gotten you an answer more quickly.